# Gulp Babel Issue Using Foundation

Tags: gulp, babeljs, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using the latest version on Foundation 6.2 and have added Babel to the project. When I add new scripts to Concat and Uglify these don't work but in the Gulp file I comment out Babel the scripts work fine.

I've added my Gulp file below, babel is only needed for Foundations bower_compnents.

Any help would be very helpful.

Jemes

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var sassPaths = [
  'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
  'bower_components/motion-ui/src'
];

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});


// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {

    return gulp.src(['src/js/assets/jquery.js', 'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js', 'src/js/assets/jquery-scrolltofixed.js', 'src/js/assets/app.js'])

    .pipe($.babel())
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/built/'))
    .pipe($.rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe($.uglify({mangle:false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
    .pipe($.notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});


// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['sass','scripts'],  function() {
  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```